# How to promisify correctly JSON.parse method with bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to promisify `JSON.parse` method but unfortunately without any luck. This is my attempt:

```
Promise.promisify(JSON.parse, JSON)(data).then((result: any) => {...
```

but I get the following error

```
Unhandled rejection Error: object
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` is a sync function. Why do you want to *promisify* it?

Comment: Because I want to create a chain of promises where JSON.parse stand at the top

Comment: @Mazzy: Where is your `data` coming from? Can you show us your complete code? There might be a better solution.

Comment: @Mazzy please change the accepted answer to bergi's. Leaving incorrect answers like this is how stackoverflow becomes a source of miss-information instead of helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`Promise.promisify`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) is thought for asynchronous functions that take a callback function. `JSON.parse` is no such function, so you cannot use `promisify` here.

If you want to create a promise-returning function from a function that might `throw` synchronously, [`Promise.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) is the way to go:

```
var parseAsync = Promise.method(JSON.parse);
…

parseAsync(data).then(…);
```

Alternatively, you will just want to use [`Promise.resolve`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html) to start your chain:

```
Promise.resolve(data).then(JSON.parse).then(…);
```

Comment: Promise.resolve(...) worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Late to the party, but I can totally understand why you might want a promisified JSON parse method which never throws exceptions. If for nothing else, then to remove boilerplate try/catch-handling from your code. Also, I see no reason why synchronous behavior shouldn't be wrapped in promises. So here:

```
function promisedParseJSON(json) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(JSON.parse(json))
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Usage, e.g:

```
fetch('/my-json-doc-as-string')
  .then(promisedParseJSON)
  .then(carryOn)
  .catch(dealWithIt)
```

Comment: JSON.parse does throw exceptions for syntacticly incorrect input:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
Please edit your answer to remove incorrect information

Comment: Yes, of course it does. That's why the try/catch is there. And that's why it is handled by rejecting the promise, so that *the promise-wrapped version* of parsing JSON does not throw synchronous exceptions, but instead rejects the promise, as it should in promise-land.

Comment: I'm sorry. I miss read your first sentence. Reading it again and I see your answer is fine. Apologies.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, `JSON.parse` is not an asynchronous function. So, don't try to *promisify* it.

---

> Because I want to create a chain of promises where JSON.parse stand at the top

Then, simply create a Promise resolved with the parsed JSON object, like this

```
Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    .then(...)
```

---

Now, to your actual question, you are getting the error,

```
Unhandled rejection Error: object
```

because, if your chain of promises is rejected, you are not handling it. So, don't forget to attach a catch handler, like this

```
Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
```

---

**READ THIS** There is a problem with the approach I have shown here, as pointed out by Bergi, in the comments. If the `JSON.parse` call fails, then the error will be thrown synchronously and you may have to write `try...catch` around the `Promise` code. Instead, one would write it as Bergi suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32310205/1903116), to create a Promise object with just the data, and then do `JSON.parse` on that Promise chain.

Comment: -1                                                                                               for not catching exceptions from the `JSON.parse()` call.

Comment: @Bergi To think of it, my answer it totally useless. Thanks for pointing out.