# How to properly code a promise returning function?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to code functions following the promise return pattern, this is a generic example of what I'm trying:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request');

var returnPromise = Promise.method(function () {
    request
      .get('http://google.com/img.png')
      .on('response', function(response) {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200)
                throw new Error('Bad request');

            else
                return response.headers;
      })    
});

returnPromise()
    .then(function (headers) {
        console.log(headers);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error handling);
    });
```

However this is not working properly as the error is yet being thrown and not handled. How should this be implemented?

Comment: You return nothing in your `Promise.method` callback.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request');

var returnPromise = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request
      .get('http://google.com/img.png')
      .on('response', resolve)
      .on('error', reject) 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `new Promise` instead of Promise.method. This is because throwing or returning from event handlers isn't captured by the promise.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request');

var returnPromise = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request
      .get('http://google.com/img.png')
      .on('response', function(response) {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200)
                reject(Error('Bad request'));

            else
                resolve(response.headers);
      })    
  });
});

returnPromise()
    .then(function (headers) {
        console.log(headers);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error handling);
    });
```

Comment: So, what's difference with `Promise.method`?

Comment: @diegoaguilar: It's [very](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32310205/1048572) [different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32160991/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi could you explain difference?

Comment: @diegoaguilar: The `Promise` constructor takes an asynchronous function with callbacks, and returns a promise. The `Promise.method` function wraps a synchronous function, and returns a function. Their signatures and purposes are completely different, I cannot even compare them.

Comment: So, just to resume, `Promise` constructor could be used instead of Promise.method, right?